# eclipse_customization.ini file and what are differences between application and product

Tags: java, eclipse, branding, eclipse-plugin

When developing an eclipse plugin, we are using a file named `plugin_customization.ini`

I wonder where I can find detailed information about which setting can be set with help of this file?

Another question is when product branding and defining an extension point in `plugin.xml` file 
we can define the extension point by the tag product or by the tag provider! What are differences! And if I am using `<provider>` like this

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">        
     <provider> 
       <run class="Test"/> 
     </provider> 
</extension>
```

can I do product branding?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecfeat/) provides some information about using the plugin_customization.ini file.

To your other question: A provider defines an installed product. This makes it a proxy for the extension of an installed product.
You can do some research on the org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProductProvider interface to get more information on this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked at the article. I think features have not been used in new Eclipse versions. (The date of article is 14 Oct 2003!). I didn't find any web page there somebody can read detailed information about start-up setting which could be changed in Plugin_customazation.ini for different plugins. But somebody can find them when debugging code with setting a breakpoint in DefaultPreferences.load() and looking at the value of properties.